# Javascript - What is the checking order for the condition statement

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements

I'm so wonder about the condition statement in Javascript. I have two example as below:

```
var myObj = {};
console.log(myObj.pro != null && myObj.pro.val != null ? 0 : 1);
console.log(myObj.pro.val != null && myObj.pro != null ? 0 : 1);
```

The second line will print a value, but the third line will raise an exception. Is the condition checked from left to right? How is it checked when we have a lot of condition operators such as OR, NOT, (), AND in the same line. Which one will be checked first?
Please correct me if I'm misunderstood.

Update: I add more complex example:

```
var !(!A || B && C && D) ? 0 : 1;
```

Comment: please add the object and possible values.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence#Table

Comment: @Ivar Is your document apply for all browser?

Comment: @CoWorker As long as the browser follows the language specifications, yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the second line `console.log(myObj.pro != null && myObj.pro.val != null ? 0 : 1);`, `myObj.pro` evaluates to `undefined` which is then compared to `null` and that returns `false`. We know that in an AND comparison, Javascript ignores the right hand side of the AND when the left hand side evaluates to `false`. This reasonable behaviour prevents the interpreter from encountering the exception-bound right hand side code which is essentially `undefined.val`

The third line just goes ahead and evaluates `undefined.val` which throws an exception and halts interpretation.

If you are interested in knowing about precedence, take a look at [this MSDN table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence#Table)

Answer (score 3):

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AND_gate

```
A   B   A AND B
0   0   0
0   1   0
1   0   0
1   1   1
```

**let's mark it like this**

```
A = myObj.pro != null 

B = myObj.pro.val != null

console.log(A && B != null ? 0 : 1);
```

because A is false we arent checking B here because false && something always be false

that's way you don't get an exception because B not even tested

in the second term

```
console.log(B && A != null ? 0 : 1);
```

B is tested before A 
and thorws exception because
**myObj.pro** is undefined  and you traying to access **myObj.pro.val**

Comment: Thank you, How it is check if the condition statement is very complex. We have (), OR, AND, NOT, .... 
Such as !(A || !B && C && D) ? 0 : 1;

Comment: each gate as it's on logic ,  you need to give an code example ,  in the case you mentioned  with OR gate if A will be true you won't chack the right side of the condition

Answer (score 1):

```
var myObj = {};
console.log(myObj.pro != null && (code which is not read)? 0 : 1);
```

In you first case, the code is executed something like above , myObj.pro !=null is false , thus without running anything else it gives 1

```
console.log(myObj.pro.val != null && myObj.pro != null ? 0 : 1);
```

In you second case when it tries to read pro.val (pro is undefined thus don't have any properties to access) gives error. 
When you try to access a property of undefined this error is returned.Example

```
var obj;
console.log(obj) // undefined;
obj.key // Cannot read property 'key' of undefined(obj is undefined in this case)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe it will get executed from left to right. But you have an Undefined property `val` . It will start with `myObj.pro` which will be `undefined`. Then `undefined.val` will definitely raise the exception here. In your second line, that didn't raise an exception because it didn't pass the first Conditional statement

Answer (score 0):

```
var myObj = {};
```

Note: myObj.pro is undefined.

```
console.log(myObj.pro.val != null && myObj.pro != null ? 0 : 1);
```

thorws exeption beacause it can't check `myObj.pro.val` first because `myObj.pro` is undefined. (cant find .val of undefined)

its like Looking for `undefined.val` thats why you've got en exeption.

Answer (score 0):

What is happening here is like this,

`console.log(myObj.pro != null && myObj.pro.val != null ? 0 : 1);`

your `&&` separates 2 conditions like this (`myObj.pro != null`)[consider 'A'] && (`myObj.pro.val != null ? 0 : 1`)[consider 'B'].

`console.log(A && B ? 0 : 1);`

so `A` gives null, `&&` don't consider going to `B`, since it got false value from `A`.

`console.log(B && A ? 0 : 1);`

but here you are trying to check value of `undefined` (in this case `myObj.pro` is `undefined`) that throws the error.

hope this helps you.

**Update**

`var !(!A || B && C && D) ? 0 : 1;`

assuming that all A,B,C,D have true values, here we go from left to right  step by step:

```
!A => false

false || B => true

true && C => true

true && D => true

!(true) => false

var false ? 0 : 1;
```

you get `0`

Answer (score 0):

Its not about the order.
In your example, **myObj = {};**

Hence it does not have property **pro** (That is **myObj.pro** is null)
Which causes the below statements first condition **myObj.pro != null** to fail. Since the condition used is && the next condition is not tested and it returns 1.

In the next statement the first condition is **myObj.pro.val != null**. Since the object myObj does not have property **pro** and **val** which is being accessed, its throwing an exception.

Answer (score 0):

try this

var myObj = {};

console.log(myObj.pro != null && myObj.pro.val != null ? 0 : 1);

console.log(myObj.pro != null && myObj.pro.val != null && myObj.pro != null ? 0 : 1);